# Is 'at tall' correct?

Tags: pronunciation

Is it correct to carry the 't' from at' over to the word 'all' as in: "I am not hungry at tall?  Like 'this for it is.

Comment: Can you please share what research you've done on this question? I also encourage you to add additional information to help us understand the question better, as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It is not literally correct to write it that way. However, it may sound that way to some people. In most American accents, a T between two vowels tends to be changed to more of a "D" sound, so Americans pronounce it almost like "adall." When Americans hear British people use a regular T sound, it can kind of sound like "at tall" to American ears.

Comment: This is definitely not right unless one is replicating an unusual pattern of speech or some such thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? This question would be easier to answer with more context: have you heard someone use this pronunciation? Are you a native speaker who uses this pronunciation, and wants to find out if it is common? Are you learning English and you want to know how to pronounce phrases like this?

Comment: It would not be correct in any dialect I am familiar with to pronounce _at all_ and _at tall_ the same, if that's what you're asking. It would, however, be perfectly common in British English (and many of its closest derivatives, like Irish and South African English) to pronounce _at all_ and _a tall_ the same way.

Comment: It is a common way to say it, especially when "at all" is being emphasized.

Comment: @SegNerd: it's not that the British people are using a regular /t/ sound. It's that they're using an aspirated /tʰ/ sound, which we (and they) mainly use at the start of syllables. So they're pronouncing *at all* as though it were a single word.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is sometimes vocalized that way, but if you were attempting to say write dialogue to show this, you would probably write it something like "a'tall" not as "at tall" or such to show a single voiced t, not two.  Similarly, normally "it is" slurred would become "'tis" not "'this".